# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object when trying to get thumbnail URL

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to get the image url of a post thumbnail, but I'm receiving an error now and I think a couple of months ago, this code used to work.

I'm using

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
```

But I'm receiving the error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

I can't seem to find any solution to it (thoug, I'm not really familiar with wordpress).

Any Ideas?

Comment: It seems like `$post->ID` is referring to a non-existing object. in which file are you using this code?

Comment: @JackJohansson  I'm using the responsive boat theme and putting in my /sections/latest_news.php file http://pasted.co/423a0a4f here's the full file

Comment: Try using `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`, and see if it helps.